# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\hmslogin\include\authenticate.inc on line 24

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have problem using PDO. After login I have this error report.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\hmslogin\include\authenticate.inc on line 24

The script is:

```
<?php
/**
* @file
* Authentication scripts.
*/

/**
* Check if username, password pair exists.
*
* @params string $username
*   The username of the person
* @params string $password
*   The password of the person
*
* @return bool
*   Returns true if the username password pair match. False otherwise.
*/
function check_password($username,$password){
  $sql = "SELECT `role`"
  . " FROM `users`"
  . " WHERE `username` = :username"
  . " AND `password` = :password";
  global $dbh;
  $res = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $res->bindParam(':username',$username);
  $password = sha1($password);
  $res->bindParam(':password',$password);
  $res->execute();
  if($row = $res->fetch()){
    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];
    return true;


  }
  return false;
}
/**
* Function to display the login form and authentication details.
*
*/
function display_login_form(){
  global $tpl;

  if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    if(check_password($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])){
      $tpl->msg = "Logged in sucessfully. Refresh page to go home";
      generate_bill();
      return;
    }
    else{
      $tpl->msg = "Username Password combination incorrect";
      $tpl->form = true;
    }
  }
  else{
    $tpl->form = true;
  }
  $tpl->content = $tpl->fetch("./template/login_form.php.tpl");
  $tpl->display("./template/index.php.tpl");

}
/**
* Function to handle the logout from sessions.
*
*/
function logout(){
  unset($_SESSION);
  session_destroy();
  global $tpl;
  $tpl->msg = "Logged out sucessfully";
  display_login_form();
}
/**
* Function to check Role
*
* Function te check if the authenticated user role has permission to access
* A particular sub module.
*
* @params string $perm
*   The perm to be checked against the authenticated user.
*
* @return boolean
*   Returns true if the user is allowed to access a particular function. False
*   otherwise.
*
*/
function check_perms($perm){
  global $auth;
  return in_array($perm,$auth[$_SESSION['role']]);
}
```

Comment: So `$dbh` is not set.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$dbh` variable does not reference the PDO object, that explains the error: `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`. You need to create an object and reference it first:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

Also, I suggest you check out [this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

**ADDITION**

After that you should use this object in a way that is similar to this:

```
$res = $dbh->prepare($query);
$res->bindValue(/* parameters */);
$res->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed your link and i edited to: $res = $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bill;","root",""); But i still got this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hmslogin\include\authenticate.inc on line 25 what is still wrong.

Comment: I added a few lines to my answer. It looks like you are still doing a mistake with this double assignment

Comment: This will work for me if you can help me connecting PostgreSQL instead of mySQL.

Comment: @AdarshSingh maybe this page can help you: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php. You basically need to change the prefix to `pgsql` instead of `mysql`, and make sure the extension is loaded.

Comment: @YuryFedorov I figured it out after posting the comment. But anyways thank you so much for the quick help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Object` has not been initialized.

If you are initializing PDO object in separate class file or in php file either you should include it in your current `php` file or inherite with your class file.

Method to create `PDO` object as below

`$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=<YOURHOST>;dbname=<DBNAME>', 'YOURUSERNAME VARIABLE', 'YOURPASSWORD VARIABLE');`